# Doxygen: Can a \post start with \ref or any other Special Command?

Tags: clang, doxygen

I'm getting an error from Clang when using `CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS` on a doxygen block that contains following line

```
\post \ref something == somethingelse
```

The warning says `"Empty paragraph passed to '\post' command"`

Is this a valid use of `\post`?
If it is, does anyone know if there's a way to suppress this warning without disabling all documentation warnings?

Cheers.

Comment: Which option did you use? I cannot find the option CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS neither in the documentation nor in the source code.

Comment: Ah yeah. That definition is for Xcode.
It's -Wdocumentation
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-Wdocumentation